# How to migrate a Windows 8.1 install from an HD to a new SSD?

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, migration

I've installed a new SSD on my laptop after removing its optical drive. My Windows 8.1 install is located on the HDD that is divided into a C:\ partition  that holds the OS and programs, and a D:\ partition that holds my files and such. I would like to migrate the OS to the SSD.

Is it possible to boot from USB and install Windows on the SSD and then format the C:\ drive and merge it into the D:\?

I ended up installing Windows 8.1 on the SSD and then used [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/) to clean up the partitions. cleaning up the partitions proved to have difficulty because the old C:\ was still being used from some settings and could not be removed with the stock windows disk manager. After a few hours of messing around with it, I eventually got everything to how I wanted it.

Comment: You can use any backup software to move OS from one place to another.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  A tutorial on the entire process would be pretty broad.  Have you done any research yet, including searching Super User?  There are a lot of ramifications, potential pitfalls, etc.  Going from novice to comfortable handling anything you might run into is a lot of territory.  Do some general research and then ask about specific things you find unclear.

Answer (score 1):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is free, boots from USB and will do exactly what you want. It will allow you to clone whole disks or just partitions and is pretty quick as well. Additionally it can image disks, allowing you backup and rapidly restore a system snapshot if you're ever thinking about doing something drastic to your system. Handy!

Comment: I will give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I chose to go a different route.

Answer (score 0):

I can only add to previous answer Acronis, Paragon programs that will help you a lot with migrating and backing up.
offtopic: you should install your SSD on the HDD place, because of SATA 3, whereas optical drive has only SATA 2 connection - this affects the speed. I have such configuration and it works great.

Comment: How much of a speed difference is it?

Comment: Acronis offers a lot and the cloning engine works a treat, I've used it a few times. Crucial SSDs come bundled with it (or at least they do here in the UK, not sure about elsewhere) if anyone's thinking about going for that particular brand.

Comment: @user2337029 somebody notice difference, somebody doesn't. here sata 2 compared to sata 3 http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2288231